# Transition via segue to a certain ViewController depending on whether user is registered/logged in or not. IOS

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

I need to create and application, that while loading doesn't require user's registration, user can work with limited application's functions. If user is registered/logged in, we need to show him more functionality.

**Conditions:**

Application must have TabBarController, NavigationController, and TableViewControleer. 
Language: Swift, Xcode 6.4

**The way I tried to do that:**

I used storyboard for adding controllers and segues.

There are two segues (type: «show (e.g.push)») with the identifiers «registeredUser», and «notRegisteredUser».
I have written the code that is executed in the method viewWillAppear of NavigationController class. It checks whether user is registered/loggedin every time when user pushes button «Settings». Depending on the result of this check user directed to the certain controller (green if he/she is registered/logged in, yellow if not).
I am not using viewDidLoad method because user at any time can push button «Exit» and application must direct him to the yellow screen at once.

```
class NavigationController:UINavigationController {

    var userisregistred:Bool!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()}

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        userisregistred = UserAccauntUtil.userRegistrationCheck()
        if (userisregistred == false ) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("notRegisteredUser", sender: self)
          }

        else if(userisregistred == true ){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("registeredUser", sender: self)
         }
    }
}
```

**Problem I have:**

After the application is loaded and I push the button "Settings", first time I am redirected to the required controller (everything works fine), but when I push "Favorites" and than again "Settings", the code from viewWillAppear is executed again and directs me to the yellow controller again moreover with a "Back" button/arrow showing on the topleft in NavBar. As a result I have a number of controllers and a back button.

I need the transition execution only one, while user should see all the controllers: TabBarController, NavigationController. 
Maybe there is another approach to such task. I would appreciate any useful information and advices.

**Bad/simple solution:**

Remove "Back" button using the code from  NotRegistedUser.swift

```
class RegisteredUser: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:false);
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Such solution simply removes symptom, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What if you use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` to get your navigation stack into a clean state before performing a segue?  (Or, slightly more complicated, `popToViewController:animated:` if the one you want is on the stack, otherwise clean the stack and segue.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I did not get to use these methods, so I do not have RootViewController. popToRootViewControllerAnimated and popToViewControllerAnimated - have nowhere to go.

 My Storyboard can be viewed here. [Storyboard](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq52fefm3m373t1/mainstoryboard.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like push segues are not what you're looking for. However, embed segues are limited to a single Container View, so you need to insert an intermediary ViewController to handle which Container View should be visible depending on the user's registered status.

The solution is detailed in http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers which was written for iOS 6 but should work the same, using the storyboard as below:

[image: Storyboard for container view]

It takes advantage of the possibility of having multiple 'Custom' segues from the View Controller to get around the single 'embed' segue limitation.

The full project (in Objective C, but easily translatable to Swift) is available here: https://github.com/mluton/EmbeddedSwapping.

The contents of [ContainerViewController.m](https://github.com/mluton/EmbeddedSwapping/blob/master/EmbeddedSwapping/ContainerViewController.m) is where the magic happens, swapping the visible view based on outside trigger.